# How to clean an Dictionary in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is this working in `Dictionary` to clean all key reference?

```
public static function cleanDic(_dic:Dictionary):void
{
    for (var eachKey:String in _dic)
    {
        delete _dic[eachKey];
    }
}
```

I'm worried about, if I delete some key during a `for` loop will cause not clean all element.

Is this that will happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by

*I'm worried about, if I delete some key during a for loop will cause not clean all element.*

but your code sample is correct, that's how a `Dictionary` can be cleaned. (Assuming that you only use `Dictionary` objects with `string` keys, since your `for` loop uses `string`. See Engineer's comment below.)

Alternatively, you can set your dictionary to a new instance - that achieves the same slightly faster:

```
var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary ();

... // use dict here      

dict = new Dictionary (); // effectively cleans the dictionary
```

The Flash garbage collector should then free all element in the dictionary that's being thrown away. **__**

Comment: +1, however "but your code sample is correct, that's how a Dictionary can be cleaned" is not correct at all. The `Dictionary`'s keys can be not only `String`s, but also other objects. So `var eachKey:String` is not correct in the code.

Comment: @Engineer Oops, sorry, you're right. I'll fix that in the answer.

Comment: thanks, what i mean a little worried is , if we loop delete Multiple obj in array or vector by useing for(var i:int=0;i<array.length;i++){array.splice(i,1)} will not delete completely , what i worry about is if delete an element in Dictionary will also cause the "Dictionary length change"  anyway, thanks all you guys help :)

Comment: @Tunied it shouldn't be an issue - you can delete as many items as you want in a loop. If you use a loop counter (`i`), though, you'll have to delete from the end of the `vector` (using `i--`). If you delete moving forward (that is, you use `i++`), your loop counter will increase but your element count will decrease and you'll have an error when you try to index a now non-existent element.)

Answer (score 10):

To begin with, I don't like any answer given here. Now, to explanation:

1. Your code will not delete all dictionary keys because dictionary keys may be any objects, not necessary strings. So, you need to iterate:

   `for (key:Object in dictionary) delete dictionary[key];`
2. There are many reasonable scenarios when you don't want to create a new dictionary - to create a new one is sometimes a very poor substitute. For example, you share values in two places in the code (wait, why else would you even make one?). Once you create a new one, the places in the code should be notified and somehow re-gain a new reference to the new object. So, some times removing all keys from the dictionary, while not exactly computationally effective, compared to creating a new one will work out better because it will keep things simple.
3. There's an interesting aspect of `Dictionary`. It is actually implemented as two hash-tables, one contains string keys, the other - pointer keys (object keys). Unfortunately, this is rather due to bad / unthoughtful design, rather then intended. It has the string hash-table inherited from `Object` and one of its own for pointer keys. Usually do *don't* want to put strings into Dictionary (or anything else which is implicitly coerced to string, like numbers or logical values), so, when you find yourself using string keys with dictionary - think again, you probably wanted to use `Object` instead.
4. What happens during the loop over dictionary: behind the scenes a collection of keys is created, and, in fact, you iterate over that collection. However, due to the dual nature of the dictionary, two keys may be taken to be the same one (for example, if you added a string `"1"` and int `1` keys - you will get only one of those. When deleting the keys, in different player versions there ware different results. In some older versions there was a bug that after deleting these keys and then serializing the dictionary one of these keys remained in it. But, again, you should avoid using strings or numbers as keys.

Comment: Hi thanks for you suggest, in my case i use and dictionary to store some element which will quickly change. ex. in first tick i will set some element in(A,B,C),and second tick i need first clean the dictionary and then push other element in(E,F,G). this may happen nearly each tick , so during this condition which is best way? crate an new Dictionary each tick or clean it? and for using Dictionary inside Object ,what i think is is faster to query in Dictionary?(is that right?) thanks for you advice again

Comment: Just to make this perfectly clear, when you say (under point 3) "don't want to put strings into Dictionary", do you mean store Strings as the value, or use them as the keys? In case of the latter, could you elaborate a little bit more? Cause that's what I've been doing for quite some time now and haven't run into any problems so far. So I'd really like to know what might be wrong with that.

Comment: I thought this would be worth to mention too - When you delete key-value pairs in your dictionary AS YOU ITERATE... it can have unpredictable results (such as leaving some items not deleted). Think of it as an array / vector if you were iterating forward (i++) as you deleted elements out of it - would you remove them all? Probably not. So I suggest gathering your keys first (with something like `for(var k:* in yourDictionary) keys[keys.length] = k;` and then iterating over the `keys` Array to call `delete yourDictionary[keys[i]];` on your dictionary elements.

Comment: The way it handles string and number keys is actually pretty bizarre.  For example, `dic[Number(1)] = "string 1";` results in a key type of 'int' (via getQualifiedClassName(key)).  On the other hand, `dic[Number(-1)] = "string 1";` results in a key type of 'String'.  Also dic["1"] results in an 'int' type key, but dic["1."] results in a String key.  That means that 1 and "1" will not produce distinct keys (they will both be 'int' of same value 1) and neither will -1 and "-1" (they will both be 'String' of same value "-1").

Comment: So in summary, it treats positive integers (even of type string) as `int` type keys, all other numbers (negative, fractional, etc.) and strings as strings, and all other objects as objects.  It seems to try to convert numeric and string keys to an `int` first, and if that fails, it just stores it as a string, and for all other types it uses its own object hash.  So it must have 3 internal hashes, one for int keys, one for string keys, and one for object keys.  Probably some kind of optimization for each of the 3 types of keys, and actually makes sense, aside from forcing string key "1" to 1.

Comment: Summary 2: Any key that's a regular-looking numeric value, whether it's a string or an int or positive or negative or fractional, will resolve to the same key.  The only exception to this is something like "-1." and -1, which will not resolve to the same key because "-1." will remain a string and -1 will become the string "-1" which is not equal to "-1.".  When I say regular-looking number, I mean how a number would look if converted to a string, so "-1" is regular-looking, but "-1." is not, because no number would ever be formatted as a string like that. "-1.5" would equate to 1.5 though.

Answer (score 2):

No need to write a method for cleaning the `Dictionary`. Just use:

```
yourdictionary = new Dictionary();
```

and GarbageCollector will do the trick.

Comment: What about `yourdictionary = null`? Seems even more direct, if you're trying to destroy the Dictionary object.

Comment: ^ Tom Auger Assigning a reference (whether to null or otherwise) has absolutely nothing to do with operating on a Dictionary object, e.g. clearing all items from it.